How to Run Docker Commands on a Remote Docker Host from a React and Node.js Application?
I am working on a cybersecurity practical setup where users can execute Docker commands from a React frontend application. The backend is built with Node.js and uses Dockerode to interact with Docker. The setup works well on a local machine, but I need to extend the functionality to run on Docker Desktop hosted on a different computer.
Current Setup:

Dockerfile: Defines a vulnerable application.
Backend: Uses Dockerode to interact with Docker.
Frontend: React application that sends commands to the backend, which executes them inside a Docker container.

Requirements:

The React frontend and the Node.js backend should communicate with a Docker host on a different computer.

Steps Taken:

Exposed Docker API: Configured Docker Desktop on the remote machine to expose the Docker API over TCP (port 2375).
Modified Backend: Updated Dockerode configuration to connect to the remote Docker host using const remoteDockerHost = "tcp://(remote-docker-host):2375";.


What's wrong with your current configuration? It looks like you've exposed the docker API for remote access and updated your backend to communicate with the the remote api. What's left?
